# How can I insert a subject line in a letter?

Tags: formatting, positioning, letters

I am writing a `letter` and I would like to insert a subject line above or below the `\opening`. How should I do this? I prefer not to use `scrlttr2` or `KOMA`.

Comment: The `letteracdp` document class defines a `letter` environment with an optional argument for the subject of the letter; it also enforce Italian conventions for the position of the addresses, though,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no specific command for subjects in `letter` style, so do something like this:

```
\bigskip
\textbf{Subject line}

\bigskip\noindent
First paragraph of text...
```

Comment: This puts the subject before the addresses...

Comment: ... at least it does in whatever example you are working with.  Perhaps you might ask a specific question with your example in it, linking to this? @Bob

Comment: I was working in the standard Letter template in the MacTex distribution.

Answer (score 17):

I know an answer has already been provided, but I would like to propose an alternative solution that I believe is more elegant. I would include the subject as the last line of the to-address, I also believe this is sometimes done intentionally so the subject is visible in windowed envelopes.

This would result in

```
...
\begin{letter}{Name\\Street\\City\\%
   \textbf{Subject: subject}%
}
...
\end{letter}
...
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer where the subject is part of the address is not that elegant if I say so myself. Although if you place a tilde (~) in as a line, you get an empty line after the address and it looks nicer.

```
...
\begin{letter}{Name \\ street \\ city \\ ~ \\ subject}

....
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using a two-line opening for this:

```
…
\begin{letter}{…}
  \opening{
    {\bf Subject: inquiry} \\[1cm]
    Dear Sirs,
  }
  …
```

which will be typeset above the text, but below the address.